# How to recovery data when delete data indexing in solr

Tags: solr

i've just run on browser:

```
/apache-solr-3.6.2/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>
```

But now i want to recovery all data indexed in Solr. How can i do it?

Note: I have not use command "&commit=true" and in case I can not access to folder solr
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the [rollback](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#A.22rollback.22) command to revert all the changes done.

e.g. `<rollback/>`

> The rollback command rollbacks all add/deletes made to the index since
>   the last commit. It neither calls any event listeners nor creates a
>   new searcher. This is an expert-level API that should only be used if
>   the application is taking complete responsibility for update
>   concurrency, replication, and sharding.

Comment: Thank you so much! i'll do it now.